Google Identity Platform (with Discourse for SSO/OICD)
I am confused by the offering of Google's IDP solution. At present we use a mix of KeyCloak &  Auth0 which both have served as login provider for our discourse community. While using the https://meta.discourse.org/t/discourse-openid-connect/103632 plugin, I managed to get the default google auth working, but what happened to the other provides configured in googles idp, such as apple, local email auth, etc.
Is there a way to redirect users to google idp for auth and then been returned to the community? I have a daunting feeling there is no login mask for the user to perform this actions like in the solutions mentioned before. Could this be?
If true, is there a way to work around this limitation?

Yes, you can redirect Users to Google Identity Platform (Google IDP) and return them to Discourse but with customization. However, Google IDP does not provide a hosted login mask that aggregates all the providers. You'll need to build or use a custom login page for this.
These are potential workarounds for the Missing Login Mask.

In your Google Identity Platform settings, ensure you’ve added and configured the additional providers (e.g., Apple, Facebook, or email/password) under the Identity Providers section.

Utilize Firebase Authentication, part of Google's Identity Platform, which offers a customizable UI and supports multiple authentication providers.

Set up a custom authentication system using Firebase to manage user sign-ins and then integrate it with Discourse.


I hope this information is useful in addressing your issue.
